# How to create a column of (x,y) pairs in a data frame

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to get a column of (x,y) coordinate pairs in my pandas data frame. I want to be able to access each part of the coordinate. For example, if the title of the column is 'pair1' I want to be able to call pair1[0] and pair1[1] to access the x and y integers respectively. Ultimately, I'd be passing these into a distance function to get the distance between 'pair1' and 'pair2'. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If your column is made up of tuples then you can split them pretty easily using apply.

```
x = [[(1,2)],[(3,4)],[(5,7)]]
df = pd.DataFrame(x,columns = ['col1'])
>>> df
     col1
 0  (1, 2)
 1  (3, 4)
 2  (5, 7)
>>> df.col1.apply(pd.Series)
    0  1
 0  1  2
 1  3  4
 2  5  7
```

Answer (score -1):

Implementing (x,y) coordinates in 1 column would be unnecessarily complex and hacky. I strongly recommend you make two columns, for example `pair1_x` and `pair1_y`. Is there a particular reason you need one column?

Comment: This is a very poor answer. It is very opinion based and doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Never done GIS, have you? GIS technologies are all about stuffing a single geometric entity into a column. That's why [GeoPandas](http://geopandas.org/) exists. I'll grant you that a simple *tuple* of x/y coordinates probably isn't the best idea, though. Probably better to get a technology designed for coordinate handling.